# export 2 gridview into excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I have 2 gridview which works like product category and product catalog.
each category have few products.

Now After the user have selected the category and view the product catalog, I would like to export this two in the excel

Example :
selected Product category: "Fruit"
the catalog is : "Apple, Banana,Orange"

I want to store the **selected** product category as well as the catalog.

For now, I only able to export the list of product catalog.(simple exporting of 1 gridview to excel)

I hope i make myself clear.

im running on asp.net c#

currenct code on the button click is

```
 string filename = String.Format("Survey Results_{0}_{1}.xls",
    DateTime.Today.Month.ToString(), DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
    Response.Charset = "";

    // SetCacheability doesn't seem to make a difference (see update)
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    // Replace all gridview controls with literals
    ClearControls(GridView2);

    // Throws exception: Control 'ComputerGrid' of type 'GridView'
    // must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
    // ComputerGrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    // Alternate to ComputerGrid.RenderControl above
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form
        = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
    Controls.Add(form);

    form.Controls.Add(GridView2);
    form.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: solved by myself. I come up with a solution to have the excel file name as the selected 'product category'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try building a dynamic `gridview` in the `codebehind` by joining the results, and instead of outputting `gridview2` you will have to export dynamically generated `gridview`.

Comment: hmmm.. i dont think its achievable, as far as I could understand. As I only want to show the selected 'product category' before the 'product catalog'. thanks though